# R multicon::composite() not running anytime NAs present

Tags: r, na, composite

My students and I keep running into this issue in multicon::composite. I love the way this function handles NAs, but lately anytime an NA is present in the dataset, it returns NAs for all rows. Here is a reproducible example:

```
BFI_1 <- c(NA,7,6,1,3,3)
BFI_6 <- c(5,7,2,7,7,7)
BFI_11 <- c(2,5,6,3,3,5)
data <- cbind(BFI_1, BFI_6, BFI_11)

multicon::composite(data,
                     R = 2,
                     nomiss = .8)
```

My Session Info:
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)/Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)/Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19043)

Any thoughts are appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Looking at the source code, it seems that the proportion of cases with missing data is based on the transpose of the input data, `t(data)`. For the transpose, the proportion is `sum(complete.cases(t(data)))/nrow(t(data))`, .66667 which is less than .8. Changing to `nomiss=.66` produces a result.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response-- huh. Had no idea that you had to look at t(data).